# Как избавиться от "Merged pull request" коммитов на гитхабе?

Tags: git, github

На гитхабе если нажать кнопку `Merge`, то в истории появляется коммит человека, который сделал PR (со временем когда он сделал) и новый твой коммит "Merged PR #123..." с текущим временем. Можно ли избавиться от последнего коммита? Или скрыть его из истории гитхаба? Они захламляют историю, и даты PR и его мержа могут сильно разниться, что ещё больше сбивает с толку.

Comment: Если во вливаемой ветке мало изменений (например только один коммит), то можно поставить галочку squash, и история будет выглядеть так, будто тот человек сделал свой коммит только что на вершине вашей основной ветки (master/main)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов можно ли на гитхабе сделать православный merge с fast forward или rebase, как если бы PR был локальной веткой?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#rebasing-and-merging-your-commits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906599/2231972 и https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fast-forward-pr

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA супер, можете написать в ответ - приму.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен fast forward merge. К сожалению, github не поддерживает его через UI, но есть два способа обойти это ограничение.

### Локальный fast forward merge

Если сделать merge локально и сделать push, то github закроет PR. Команды, чтоб это сделать:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --ff-only your-branch # бранч, из которого делался PR
$ git push
```

### Git Hub Action

Можно использовать [Fast Forward PR](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fast-forward-pr) action. Это позволяет делать merge с fast forward используя специальный коментарий в PR.

Answer (score 0):

Если считаете, что коммиты слияния захламляют вам историю, то просто не создавайте их.
Используйте слияние либо через squash, либо через православный rebase. Если в главной ветке не было новых коммитов, то последний вариант даст вам как раз быструю перемотку Fast Forward

[image: options for merging pull requests]